# Cannot downcast object of type Any to Int when accessing from dictionary

Tags: swift

I have a Gfycat struct that represents the data I want to store after making a network call to the Gfycat API.

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String: Any]

struct Gfycat {
    let id: String
    let number: Int
}
```

In an extension to the Gfycat struct, I wrote a failable initializer that takes a dictionary of type [String: Any] as its argument. This dictionary is then used to assign values to the struct's properties. This is the original init method I wrote:

```
extension Gfycat {
    init?(dictionary: JSONDictionary) {
        guard let id = dictionary["gfyId"] as? String,
            let number = dictionary["gfyNumber"] as? Int { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.number = number
    }
}
```

The problem is that when accessing a value from the dictionary, I cannot downcast the value from Any to Int. I must first downcast Any to String, then convert that string to Int. Is this a bug or rather a feature of Swift that I don't understand?

This was my solution:

```
extension Gfycat {
    init?(dictionary: JSONDictionary) {
        guard let id = dictionary["gfyId"] as? String,
            let uncastedNumber = dictionary["gfyNumber"] as? String,
            let number = Int(uncastedNumber) else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.number = number
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that your dictionary is keyed with strings and the values are strings, not ints.

Comment: What is your JSON? If your JSON has a string masquerading as a number (ie "1.0" instead of 1.0) then this is the correct behavior.  Its properly a String and needs an explicit conversion to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I must first downcast Any to String, then convert that string to Int. Is this a bug or rather a feature of Swift that I don't understand?

It's neither a bug nor a feature of Swift. It's a fact about the dictionary you're working with. This thing *is* a String, *not* an Int. So you cannot cast it to an Int.

Comment: Yeah, I get it now. Thanks. I needed to wake up a little more. -_-

Comment: @matt Hi matt, if I fetch data, the data which is a `dictionary` from network, and the `dictionary`'s key and value must be String Value? The value could be `Int` or other type value?